# how can I convert event.key into event.keyCode?

Tags: javascript, events, key, keycode

event.keyCode is now deprecated, so it's recommended to use event.key, but how can I get the "keyCode" from the "key"?

Now event.keyCode (but also event.which) are deprecated.

[event.keyCode deprecation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)
[event.which deprecation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which)

Comment: You can simply research on the net and not ask/answer your questions. 
The best is to use `which` as explained in [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

Comment: event.which is deprecated too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'a'.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)`

why `toUpperCase()`? because the `keyCode` is the ASCII code of the uppercase letter

'a' keyCode is 65
'A' keyCode is 65

`'A'.charCodeAt(0)` is 65, but
`'a'.charCodeAt(0)` is 97

**WARN:** this works only for A-z and 0-9 characters, not for Arrow*, Escape, Enter etc. keys